# How to get json Object From json file

Tags: java, json, spring, deserialization

I have a json file SenderTest.json in my src/test/resources package of my project. I think my approach of deserializing the json object to java object is right.

```
JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
String jsonStrng = json.toString();

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
Animal animal = mapper.readValue(jsonStrng, Animal.class);
```

but I am struggling to understand how to get the SenderTest.json from recources package into this JsonObject

Comment: The json will only be available for the tests, as it's included in the test/resources directory. To read it you need to do getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("SenderTest.json") and read the stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
Animal  animal = mapper.readValue(new FileInputStream(new File("SenderTest.json")), Animal.class);
```

Here we are passing the `InputStream` as the first parameter in the `readValue` method

Answer (score 0):

If your question is "how do I read a file located within the project itself", it's been asked before - try out the following question for an example: [Read file from a folder inside the project directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745018/read-file-from-a-folder-inside-the-project-directory)

If you're actually asking "how do I read the file without working through Object mapping and explicit deserialization", you can do the following:

```
new JSONObject( IOUtils.toString( new FileInputStream( path.toString() ), "UTF-8" ) );
```